# The <ul> in my nav extends to the side of the page

Tags: html, css, web

I have a nested `<ul>` within my nav ul. When the `<ul>` has only one element its padding is fine and the `<li>` fits nicely. However when I have more than one element in the nested `<ul>` it extends to the side of the page. I can see nothing to do with padding changes in my `:first-child` or anything in my css for the nested `<ul>`.

The nested ul with multiple elements
[image: The nested ul with multiple elements]

The nested ul with only one element
[image: The nested ul with only one element]

Here is the HTML:

```
<header id="header" class="alt">
            <h1><strong><a href="index.html">South Somerset Motocross Club</a></strong></h1>
            <nav id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a>Info</a>
          <ul>
                            <li><a href="pages/info/clubrules.html">Club Rules</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/info/preracecheck.html">Pre-Race Bike Check</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/info/jobdescriptions.html">Job Descriptions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/info/racefees.html">Race Fees</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/info/groupsandages.html">Groups And Ages</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
                    <li><a>About Us</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="pages/aboutus/ourheritage.html">Our Heritage</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/aboutus/committee.html">Committee</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a>News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/fixtures.html">Fixtures</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    #header nav {
        height: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
        position: absolute;
        right: 1.25em;
        top: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

        #header nav ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

            #header nav ul li {
                color: #fff;
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                margin-left: 1em;
            }


            #header nav ul li ul {
                display: none;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: #eee;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }

            #header nav ul li:hover ul {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
            }

            #header nav ul li ul li {
                border-radius: 4px;
                margin: 0 0 0 0;
                padding-left: 4px;
                padding-top: 1px;
                padding-right: 4px;
                width: 100%;
                color: black;
                font-size: 12pt;
            }

        #header nav ul li ul li a {
            color: #111;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            display: block;
        }

        #header nav ul li ul li a:hover {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
        }

        #header.alt nav ul li ul li a:hover {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
        }

        #header.alt nav ul li ul li:hover {
            background-color: #3477ff;
        }

        #header nav ul li ul li:hover {
            background-color: #3477ff;
        }

        #header.alt nav ul li ul li a {
            color: #000;
            padding: 0;
            display: block;
        }


                #header nav ul li a {
                    -moz-transition: color 0.1s ease-in-out;
                    -webkit-transition: color 0.1s ease-in-out;
                    -ms-transition: color 0.1s ease-in-out;
                    transition: color 0.1s ease-in-out;
                    color: #000;
                    display: inline-block;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }

                    #header nav ul li a:hover {
                        color: #000;
                    }
```

Any ideas on how I can keep the width of the `<ul>` to the max length of one of the items?

Comment: add some code like jsfiddle

Comment: @LaljiTadhani my bad forget the most important thing haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add display block in

```
#header nav ul li ul li {
            border-radius: 4px;
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            padding-left: 4px;
            padding-top: 1px;
            padding-right: 4px;
            width: 100%;
            color: black;
            font-size: 12pt;
            display:block;
        }
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/hp02dayn/)

Comment: Thank you!! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Yop!

i checked Your css and the problem was here:

```
#header nav ul li ul li {
                border-radius: 4px;
                margin: 0 0 0 0;
                padding-left: 4px;
                padding-top: 1px;
                padding-right: 4px;
                width: 100%;
                color: black;
                font-size: 12pt;
            }
```

Which i changed to this:

```
#header nav ul li ul li {
                border-radius: 4px;
                margin: 0 0 0 0;
                padding-left: 4px;
                padding-top: 1px;
                padding-right: 4px;
                //width: 100%;
                display:table;
                color: black;
                font-size: 12pt;
            }
```

So now it's getting the width of longest item :)

Hope i helped!

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't change the width of the `<ul>` items, and the so actual list's width is still the same just the elements fit next to eachother instead of one below the other.

Comment: did You noticed the "display:table" ?
It's the one that is making elements position one after another.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, didn't see that line. Fixed now anyway. Thanks anyway!